# Better way to find the mode of a data set C++

Tags: c++, math, vector, dictionary, dataset

I'm trying to find the mode of a data set in C++. I wrote a function that seems to do it but I don't like that I have to return an empty vector in the case that there's no mode. Is there a more efficient way to do this? Here's my code:

```
vector<double> findMode(vector<double> v)
{
    map<double, int> modeStorage;
    vector<double> mode;
    int mostRepetitions = 2;
    for (double i : v)
    {
        ++modeStorage[i];
    }
    for (map<double, int>::iterator it = modeStorage.begin(); it != modeStorage.end(); ++it)
    {
        if (it->second >= mostRepetitions)
        {
            mostRepetitions = it->second;
        }
    }
    for (map<double, int>::iterator it = modeStorage.begin(); it != modeStorage.end(); ++it)
    {
        if (it->second == mostRepetitions)
        {
          mode.push_back(it->first);
        }
    }
return mode;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Just to clarify: If there aren't at least two of the same of any one value in the data set, then there is no mode. That's why mostRepetitions has to be >= 2. If the function finds that there is no mode (all the values exist only once in the set) then it returns an empty vector. That's my problem. I have to test if the vector is empty once I get it back from the function, and that feels sloppy to me (if it's not, just tell me and I'll shut up).

Comment: And what are you going to return in case if there is no mode?

Comment: When possible prefer reference variables to avoid unnecessary copying `findMode(vector<double>& v)`.

Comment: What if there's a vector with no repetitions?  Shouldn't that be the mode?  IOW, why do you have
`
        int mostRepetitions = 2;
`

Comment: @wesley.mesquita Thanks. I've been told that before. I'm just new to programming and references are still confusing to me. I'll keep it in mind though.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I tried to answer your question in my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a snippet, with a little different approach:
1) If we get a vector with no mode, we throw an exception.
2) We return only the mode.
3) The function is a template, but you can substitue `T` for your type.

I tried to explain the algorithm in the comments.

OBS: There is some lambdas that helped me to write tests and they need C++11 support. If you don´t have or don´t know, focus on `T findMode(const std::vector<T>& vec )`.

```
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<string>
#include<stdexcept>

#include<iostream>


template<typename T>
T findMode(const std::vector<T>& vec ){

    if(vec.size() == 0){
        throw std::domain_error("No mode for empty vector");
    }
    else if(vec.size() == 1)
        return vec[0];

    // copy the original, don´t alter the input
    std::vector<T> v(vec); 

    // Order just to group same elements
    // T MUST implement '>' operator. Which is trivial
    // for primitive types.
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());  

    typename std::vector<T>::iterator it ; 

    it = v.begin(); 

    size_t largest_count = 0;
    T mode;
    bool flag = false; // this flag indicates when we found 2 equal modes
    while( it != v.end() ){

        T m = *it;
        size_t count = 1;

        while( it != v.end() && *++it == m ){   
            count++;            
        }   

        if(count > largest_count){
            largest_count = count;
            mode = m;
            flag = false;
        }
        else if(count == largest_count){
            flag = true;
        }
    }

    if(flag){
        // if we found a count as large as the largest, 
        // we have no made, so, throw exception
        throw std::domain_error("No mode for vector");
    }

    return mode;    
}

template<typename T>
bool test(const std::vector<T> v, const T& expected_mode){
    T mode;
    try{
        return findMode<T>(v) == expected_mode;
    }catch(const std::domain_error& de){
        return false;
    } 
}

int main(){


    const std::vector<int> vec_int = {1};
    std::cout << [&](){ return test<int>(vec_int, 1) == true ? "OK" : "NOK"; }() << " for {1}" 
        << std::endl;

    // This test is OK, if returns false, there is no mode
    const std::vector<int> vec_int2 = {1,1,2,2};
    std::cout << [&](){ return test<int>(vec_int2, 1) == false ? "OK" : "NOK"; }() 
        << " for {1,1,2,2}" << std::endl;

    // This test is OK, if returns false, there is no mode
    const std::vector<int> vec_int3 = {1,1,1,1};
    std::cout << [&](){ return test<int>(vec_int3, 1) == true ? "OK" : "NOK"; }() 
        << " for {1,1,1,1}" << std::endl;

    // This test is OK, if returns false, there is no mode
    const std::vector<double> vec_double = {6.25, 1.1, 1.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.5, 6.25, 6.25, 6.25, 6};
    std::cout << [&](){ return test<double>(vec_double, 6.25) == true ? "OK" : "NOK"; }() 
        << " for {6.25, 1.1, 1.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.5, 6.25, 6.25, 6.25, 6}" << std::endl;


    // This test is OK, if returns false, there is no mode
    const std::vector<char> vec_char ={'0', 'X', 'D', 'E', 'A', 'D', 'B', 'E', 'E', 'F'};
    std::cout << [&](){ return test<char>(vec_char, 'E') == true ? "OK" : "NOK"; }()
        << " for {'0', 'X', 'D', 'E', 'A', 'D', 'B', 'E', 'E', 'F'}" << std::endl;


    return 0;   
}
```